# Magento 2 - new inscription newsletter error (no such entity with customerId = 0)

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-2.1.7, newsletter

I always have this error when I try to register to **newsletter** in **`Magento 2`**. The error is:

> No such entity with `customerId = 0`

If I try to add it directly from database, it works perfectly.